# Flutter: simple socket.io testing - Websocket pending

Tags: flutter, socket.io

I have a super simple socket.io node server like below

```
// Socket!
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("a user connected");
  socket.on("msg", (aaa) => {
    console.log(aaa);
  });
  socket.on("fromServer", (_) => print(_));
  console.log(socket.handshake.query)
});
```

And, here is my Flutter code to connect to the server

```
  // Dart client
  IO.Socket socket = IO.io(
      'http://192.168.219.102:7199',
      IO.OptionBuilder()
          .setTransports(['polling'])
          .disableAutoConnect()
          .setQuery({"hee": 'asdf'})
          .build());
  socket.connect();
  socket.onConnect((_) {
    print(_);
  });
```

On the network tab, I see two requests

- 101 HTTP 490ms
- 101 WS   Pending

When I connect to the `socket.io` server from the other node.js server, I see the console.log of `a user connected` on the terminal. However, I see nothing from Flutter.

What can I do to receive the socket message on the server and connect the device.